# Actionscript object syncronization

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have 3 timers that access and modify the same resource (an array).

Is there any way to avoid modifying and accessing the array in the same time in actionscript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't worry about that - AS3 is single-threaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the correct answer (for the most part). You can run multi-threaded code now, but you have to set it up yourself and there isn't much documentation yet.

Comment: Agree, due to single threaded nature of Flash (without getting on the bleeding edge with ActionScript workers) you generally don't have to deal with the possibility of two methods executing at the same time and messing up the memory in the process.  Believe this is one big reason threading has been left out for so long.  Timers may end up processing things in a strange order depending on the way things are setup in this case you just need to use chains of method calls (synchronized as opposed to asynch with multiple timers) where applicable.